# convert java class to jframe form Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-8

I have created multiple JFrame forms in NetBeans. Those have been automatically converted into java classes by the Netbeans. The program still works fine but I can't access the design feature in Netbeans since they are java classes. Anyone that knows how to convert them back to Jframe forms or how to use the design feature in java classes?
Thanks

Comment: Netbeans forms consist of two files, the class file and the form file, the class file is auto-generated (or parts thereof) from the form file, if you've lost the form file, there is, AFKIA, nothing you can do

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, I think I'll have to copy and paste then